# Laravel - Validation rules grouping

Tags: laravel, validation

I'm trying to validate a form where user can modify the contacts and choose or change a preferred contact. There are three cases in which fields can be passed for the validation.

1. contact, contact_id, preferred ( updating a contact and setting it as preferred )
2. contact_id, preferred ( setting a contact as preferred )
3. contact, contact_id ( updating a contact )

Now I'm struggling with validation rules to pair these fields, so a missing field in any case will generate an error.

Edit : This is the rule I came up with :-

```
public function rules() {
    $request = Request::all();

    return [
          'contact_id' => [
            'bail',
            'numeric',
            'not_in:0',
            Rule::exists('user_contact')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('contact_id', $request['contact_id'])->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
            }),
        ],
        'contact' => [
            'bail',
            'required_with:contact_id',
            'regex:/^[7-9][0-9]{9}$/',
            'unique:user_contact,contact_no'
        ],
        'is_preferred' => [
            'sometimes',
            'required_with:contact_id',
            'in:true,false',
        ]
    ];
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to post the code from your attempts at this.

Comment: @wheelmaker I have update the post.